# eclipse - project facets - java v1.7 is not available

Tags: java, version, java-7, facet

I have an Eclipse project that uses java v1.7 - I cloned the project to my Mac and now have a facet problem.  jre7 is installed and included in the build path.  I have cleaned and restarted Eclipse but java v 1.7 is not available in the list of versions in the Project Facets tab.  Please advise

Comment: Some Eclipse plugins and functions require a full JDK (as opposed to a JRE). Also, does Java7 show up in the Java Preferences panel on your Mac?

Comment: is it available in the global preferences? also, have you tried searching for the jdk manually so that it gets added?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  What's curious is only the one project does not list it in the project facets tab.  All other projects list it just fine.